# Call to a member function all() on string laveral

Tags: php, laravel-5

Am following tutorials in youtube on laravel, am using laravel 5.6.
I get an error when try display error
here the codes

This is the view

```
 @if (isset($errors)&&count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger fade show">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" area-label="Close">
                <span area-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li><strong>{!! $error !!}}</strong></li>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
```

This is the  Controller

```
  return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new company');
```

So I don't know where I went wrong Somebody could help me

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I would guess, `Call to a member function all() on string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and display in session

```
 return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new company');
```

Display in template

```
@if(session('errors'))
     {{session('errors')}}
@endif
```

You are displaying single error so **No** need to add `@foreach`

Answer (score 2):

### You can use laravel's redirecting with flashed session data

controller =>

```
 return redirect()->back()->with('errors','Error creating new company');
```

---

view =>

```
@if(session('errors'))
    {{session('errors')}}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help but it should be 'errors' so it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new company');
```

you are setting "errors" to a string

The following code should work for you without changing your markup:

```
return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Error creating new company']);
```

In your code you are using a foreach so the `$errors` item needs to be iterable.

You can add more errors to the array, for example:

```
return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Error creating new company', 'Second error']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it works but it prints array instead of string